# I'm fetching data from an API in an async function in React and it works fine, but when I return the data I get a pending promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, async-await, fetch

I have the following React and TypeScript code:

```
const fetchData = async () => {
    const res: any = await fetch("https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=thoughtsofadyingatheist&type=track&limit=30", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer BQD2JKxAuqmgsNKgWx6JiRMCskc3l1FK3VsHfOah3ey86GC8EmGBlrEGAfTCyVB1cFo2TDVQYQm8RvB_YQD6V9cXUf_HER0dfBeLc_AZ0N56VNOrsLyt2yzK6gaD5WarThefqmZj68ODXUVrLwQYfuocahIUhWOEO4WuziwVvloE",
      },
    });
    const data: any = await res.json();
    console.log(data.tracks.items);
    return data.tracks.items;
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const data: any = fetchData(); 
    console.log(data);
    setLoading(false);
  }, []);
```

When I print the data to the console from the `fetchData` function I get the expected data, but when I print it from the `useEffect` hook I get a pending promise like this: `Promise {<Pending>}`.

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `useEffect` hook should be like the following code snippet. This happens because an async function returns **always** a `Promise` and you should `await` it or use `asyncFunction.then(result => {})` to get its result.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData().then(data => { 
      console.log(data);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }, []);
```

To use `await` in `useEffect` it needs to be with a [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) unfortunately because `useEffect` doesn't support async functions yet.

```js
 useEffect(() => {
   (() => async {
     const data = await fetchData();
     console.log(data);
     setLoading(false);
   })();
 }, []);
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked but can you explain why it does?

Comment: I've edited the answer with an explanation

Comment: I've also added the solution with await

Comment: I had totally forgotten that async functions always return a Promise. Thank you very much!! You're the GOAT